# Invalid character while converting from JSON to XML using jsonlib

Tags: java, xml, json, xml-serialization, json-lib

I'm trying to convert a JSON string to XML using jsonlib in Java.

```
    JSONObject json = JSONObject.fromObject(jsonString); 
    XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer();
    String xml = serializer.write( json );  
    System.out.println(xml);
```

The error that I get is

```
    nu.xom.IllegalNameException: 0x24 is not a legal NCName character
```

The problem here is that I have some properties in my JSON that are invalid XML characters. eg. I have a property named "$t". The XMLSerializer throws the exception while trying to create a XML tag in this name because $ is not allowed in XML tag names. Is there any way in which I can override this XML well formedness check done by the serializer?

Comment: why would you want to override that check (and generate invalid xml)?

Comment: I'm trying to use the Google REST API. After firing the webservice, I get a JSON response. I have a tree viewer that displays XML in the tree structure. So I have to convert JSON to XML to display it as a tree. But in JSON "$" is a valid property name. Google API returns property names like "$t", "gCal$timesCleaned" etc. So I'm getting an error when converting it to XML.

Answer (score 0):

First I'd suggest to add the language you are using (it is Java, right?).

You could override the method where it checks your XML tag name to do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the spec for the json-lib XMLSerializer and to my surprise it seems to have no option for serialising a JSON object whose keys are not valid XML names. If that's the case then I think you will need to find a different library.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over `json.keySet` (recursively if necessary) and replace invalid keys  with valid ones (using `remove` and `add`).