# Issue while converting JSON to XML in Java

Tags: java, xml, json

I have some **json data** which is accessed from a third party server. It contains large content and starts like

```
   [
   {
      "id":1845,
      "title":"Llm In Transnational Oil, Gas And Energy Law By Online Learning",
      "category_id":4,
      "sub_category_id":null,
      "timestamp":"2013-05-15T11:56:19.168508Z",
      "start_time":"2013-09-29T15:00:00+01:00",
      "end_time":"2014-12-19T19:30:00+00:00",
      "summary":"Develop a deep, practical understanding of how to resolve the challenges posed\r\nby national authorities to oil, gas and energy production.\r\n"
...
```

I cannot convert this JSON to XML, even using `JSONSerializer` and `XMLSerializer`. I got the following error:
`ncname 0*20 illegal character`

I also tried some `org.json` libraries like `JSONTokenizer` and `JSONArray` which retrieve only text but do not generate any XML output.

Comment: Show us the code you have tried.

Comment: The format of a `ncname` is defined here: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114/#NT-NCName From the error it seems like your JSON is mapped to a key that doesn't conform to that rule. `0x20` indicates a space character somewhere the parser doesn't allow one.

Comment: Also, a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7928535/785663